# Test whether certain variables (in different versions) appear in data

Tags: r, string, vector, string-matching

Say that I have a character vector (vector **(A)**) that holds a string in each of its elements (thus separate strings: A1, A2, A3, etc.). I want to compare each string against another vector of strings (vector **(B)**), to see whether there's a match.

For example, this would mean that when vector A has the string `xyz` in its first element, and vector B has `xyz_blah` in whatever element, I will get `TRUE` when testing whether A-1 exists in B-whatever.

```r
vec_a <- c()
vec_b <- c()

vec_a[1] <- "xyz"
set.seed(2020) ; vec_b[sample(1:100, size = 1)] <- "xyz_blah"

grepl(vec_a, vec_b)

## [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [27] FALSE  TRUE
```

But my case happens to be more complicated. First, I have more than one string in vector A that I want to test for existence in vector B.

```r
vec_a[1] <- "xyz"
vec_a[2] <- "vvtp"
set.seed(2020) 
vec_b[sample(1:100, size = 1)] <- "xyz_blah"
vec_b[sample(1:100, size = 1)] <- "vvtp_blah"
```

And instead of 2 `TRUE`s, `grepl(vec_a, vec_b)` returns all `FALSE` and the error:

> Warning message: In grepl(vec_a, vec_b) :   argument 'pattern' has
> length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Second, sometimes I know that strings in vector A *might* come with different additions (or "versions") when they appear in vector B. For example, vector A could contain `dog_height` and/or `dog_weight`, and so might vector B. So I want to specify not only the "stem" string, but also potential versions, and test whether each appears in vector B. It becomes even more complicated when my data could have either `dog_weight` or `weight_dog` (but not both), so I know that `dog` and `weight` have to exist both in one string in vector B, but not the exact pattern.

### A Coherent Example

I have data from a clinic of pets.

- Column headers have the kind of animal and type of measure.
- Sometimes, there's no type of measure, just the kind of animal.
- Separators between kind of animal and type of measure are inconsistent (sometimes it's `_` or `~` or `-`)
- Type of animal and kind of measure can swap positions

```r
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(~dog_weight, ~dog_height, ~cat_weight, ~cat_height, ~hamster, ~`rabbit~weight`, ~parrot_height, ~`weight-guinea_pig`)
```

And therefore:

```r
names(df)

[1] "dog_weight"        "dog_height"        "cat_weight"        "cat_height"        "hamster"           "rabbit~weight"     "parrot_height"     "weight-guinea_pig"
```

Now let's say that I want to query my data and see whether I have:

- weight data for dogs
- height data for dogs
- weight data for guinea pigs
- any data for hamster

One approach would be to specify a function that takes in the name of animals and type of measure, such that a function called `locate_in_df()` would have three arguments:

- `vector_of_animals` which has `c(dog, guinea_pig, hamster)`; and
- `type_of_measure` which can be `c(height, weight, any)`
- dataframe to check against

```r
animals <- c("dog", "guinea_pig", "hamster")
measures <- c("weight", "height")

locate_in_df(vector_of_animals = animals,
             type_of_measure = measures,
             dataframe = df)
```

And will return:

```r
  animal     weight height any  
  <chr>      <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>
1 dog        TRUE   TRUE   TRUE 
2 guinea_pig TRUE   FALSE  TRUE 
3 hamster    FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
```

Another approach could specify a vector of animals and type of measures and test it against `names(df)` so that:

```r
vec_of_query <- c("dog, height", "dog, weight", "guinea_pig, weight", "hamster")
```

And then some sort of `grepl()`-like thing to return `TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE`? It would be less granular than the first approach but still informative, and it circles back to the beginning of this post discussing matching strings between vectors. Problem is, I don't know how to address either of these ideas. Any idea how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `locate_in_df` like this:

```r
locate_in_df <- function(vector_of_animals, type_of_measure, dataframe) {
   haystack <- names(dataframe)

   vs <- apply(sapply(type_of_measure, function(x) {
     lapply(vector_of_animals, function(y) {
       any(grepl(x, haystack) & grepl(y, haystack))
     })
   }), 2, unlist)
   
   tibble(animals = vector_of_animals, 
          as.data.frame(vs), 
          any = sapply(vector_of_animals, function(x) any(grepl(x, haystack))))
}
```

Such that

```r
locate_in_df(vector_of_animals = animals,
              type_of_measure = measures,
              dataframe = df)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   animals    weight height any  
#>   <chr>      <lgl>  <lgl>  <lgl>
#> 1 dog        TRUE   TRUE   TRUE 
#> 2 guinea_pig TRUE   FALSE  TRUE 
#> 3 hamster    FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, @Allan. Just one thing -- `haystack <- names(df)` needs to be `haystack <- names(dataframe)` to match with `locate_in_df`'s data argument.